# Read a previous line in a file in android

Tags: android

i can read the next line in a file stored in the assets folder. 
But how do read the previous line by click of a button.
my file is stored in the assets folder

Comment: You just save the last read line (next time that is the previous line) continuously?

Answer (score 1):

if you got a small size file, just read all previous lines starting from the first line  to the line you can read or even to the last line ,  split them by "\n"  and get the previous line by its index, this is not a good way, however i recommend you to post your code so we can  help you better ^_*